# Registar asks for a domain instead of IP address for the nameservers of my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, domain-registrar

Let's say I have a DNS server at home with IP 123.123.123.123. How can I tell my registrar to use this server as the nameserver for my domain? I can't just provide it with an IP address.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't provide it with an IP address?

Comment: In a box, I need to enter the nameservers of my domain. I need to provide 'ns1.example.com' for example and I can't just enter '123.123.123.123'.

Comment: OT but at least to help http://serverfault.com/questions/82761/why-does-my-registrar-only-want-name-server-names

Answer (score 2):

the registrar expects a fully qualified domain name as your DNS servers.  You need to register your dns server with the registrar (inside your registrar account somewhere you should be able to create a host record that points to your dns server's ip address) before you can use it as a DNS server.

Comment: I am not sure to have understood fully your answer. You are telling me that my registrar expects an FQDN and that I should also be able to specify the IP address of this FQDN somewhere on my registrar's site. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes.  step 1, create the host entries for your name servers using the ip addresses.  step 2, use that host as your own domains name server.  Note: in Godaddy step 1 is done under "Host Names" on the domain page.

Answer (score 0):

is your isp delegating your domain dns to you? to have your own server handling dns for your domain, they must delegate the dns for your domain to you. in that case, you have to give them the ip because your dns servers has not become resolvable yet before you set up your own dns servers at that point. otherwise there will be an infinite loop.

these are called glue records and ips must be known to the party that delegates you the dns (your isp that is).

either you or your isp have misunderstood something completely. in the latter case you should change the isp right away because they do not know what they are doing. in the former case, probably they are handling your domain in the first place and you don't need your dns servers in any case (though you can still set up forward or cache servers if you want).

Comment: I don't understand what my ISP has to do with this. My ISP is providing me with an IP address and I want to use it to host my DNS and web servers. Isn't it my registrar that is supposed to delegate my domain to me? Replacing 'isp' by 'registrar' in your answer actually makes sense. It is true that my registrar is also currently hosting my website, which might explain why it doesn't let me specify an IP address has my nameserver. Is it a normal behavior among registrars?

Comment: that makes sense and you are right about using registrar. i used isp because in most cases i do they are the same guys, but still your registrar need to let you specify ip address of your dns servers in addition to server names, if you are going to run your dns service, otherwise they (or anyone else) will not be able to find your dns servers or any of your servers in your domain.